# Run my particular block of code when receive notification from particular app even when app is not running

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

Is there any broadcast receiver or a `NotificationListnerService` class.
Basically, **I want to run code in background when received notification from particular app and show some result on UI thread**. You can relate this to something like Chathead activates automatically when message is received from WhatsApp or messenger
I am new to android sorry if ask something wrong
Please share some working code if you know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a service and like below

Manifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".MyNotificationListener"
  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
 </intent-filter>
```

add permission

```
android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE
```

and Service

```
public class MyNotificationListenerextends NotificationListenerService {  

Context context;  

@Override  

public void onCreate() {  

    super.onCreate();  
    context = getApplicationContext();  

}  
@Override  

public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {  
    String pack = sbn.getPackageName();  
    String ticker ="";  
    if(sbn.getNotification().tickerText !=null) {  
        ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();  
    }  
    Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;  
    String title = extras.getString("android.title");  
    String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();  
    int id1 = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);  
    Bitmap id = sbn.getNotification().largeIcon;  


    Log.i("Package",pack);  
    Log.i("Ticker",ticker);  
    Log.i("Title",title);  
    Log.i("Text",text);  

    Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");  
    msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);  
    msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);  
    msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);  
    msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);  
    if(id != null) {  
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        id.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);  
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();  
        msgrcv.putExtra("icon",byteArray);  
    }  
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);  


}  

@Override  

public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {  
    Log.i("Msg","Notification Removed");  

}  }
```

Comment: not working bro.. apply all the things and I have use this code before also. I can't get any log

Comment: what you write I'll write same in a new project make MyNotificationListener class add manifest But does not get any logs from notification of like WhatsApp